# How to sort python dictionary by main and sub dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that stores countries and offices I need to sort them by 
**Country** then by **office locations**. I manage to sort them by **Country** by doing this;

```
sorted_list = [[id, desc] for id, desc in sorted(locations.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1]['name']))
```

however when I tried to do **items[1]['cities']['names']** it didnt work because obviously index is string not integer.

> (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str )

What I need to do is Sort By Country first and Sort By cities inside

**Expected Output**:

Austria -> *Gramatneusiedl / Vienna, Home Office, Lenzing, Schoerfling, Weissenstein*

Belgium -> *Antwerp, Brussels, Home Office, Oostende*

**Initial Input**:

```
 locations = '2248': {
            'name': 'Austria',
            'cities': [{
                'OptionId': 2289,
                'name': 'Gramatneusiedl / Vienna'
            }, {
                'OptionId': 2290,
                'name': 'Lenzing'
            }, {
                'OptionId': 2291,
                'name': 'Schoerfling'
            }, {
                'OptionId': 2292,
                'name': 'Weissenstein'
            }, {
                'OptionId': 2293,
                'name': 'Home Office'
            }]
        },

    '2249': {
                'name': 'Belgium',
                'cities': [{
                    'OptionId': 9367,
                    'name': 'Oostende'
                }, {
                    'OptionId': 2294,
                    'name': 'Antwerp'
                }, {
                    'OptionId': 2295,
                    'name': 'Brussels'
                }, {
                    'OptionId': 2296,
                    'name': 'Home Office'
                }]
```

Comment: I did post please check above

Comment: 2 line below quote I wrote expected output and initial input is dictionary called locations

Comment: updated question to make it more clear

Comment: Are you just trying to print the items in order?  Or do you want to maintain order within your dictionary?

Comment: I am using them inside a dropdown in html

Comment: https://eval.in/925686 ?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys in Python do *not* guarantee order.  You can see this SO post for more details: [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared).  There are ways to do it, and depending on what version of Python you are using, it might be different.

If you just want to print the items in order, there is an easy way to manage it using the `json` library.

```
import json
ordered = {v['name']: sorted([i['name'] for i in v['cities']]) for v in locations.values()}
json.dumps(ordered, sort_keys=True)
```

This will print the following result:

```
{
  "Austria": [
    "Gramatneusiedl / Vienna",
    "Home Office",
    "Lenzing",
    "Schoerfling",
    "Weissenstein"
  ],
  "Belgium": [
    "Antwerp",
    "Brussels",
    "Home Office",
    "Oostende"
  ]
}
```

If you want to maintain order within the dictionary, then use an OrderedDict object.  OrderedDicts remember *insertion* order.  So we can sort all of the items based on the value of the *name* key before creating the final dictionary.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered = OrderedDict()
# sort each dictionary by their name field
sorted_by_country = sorted(locations.values(), key = lambda x:x['name'])
for v in sorted_by_country:
    ordered[v['name']] = sorted([i['name'] for i in v['cities']])
```

Comment: as of 3.7 dictionaries are guaranteed to be insertion order.

Comment: Right.  I think it's actually as of 3.6, and that's discussed in the other post I linked to.  If you are worried about what version of Python someone may be using to run your code, it makes sense to cover your bases with `OrderedDict`.

Comment: insertion ordered in 3.6 only for CPython and not guaranteed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965481/python-3-6-collections-document-mistake-found/47965522#47965522  https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
locations = {'2248': {'cities': [{'OptionId': 2289, 'name': 'Gramatneusiedl / Vienna'}, {'OptionId': 2290, 'name': 'Lenzing'}, {'OptionId': 2291, 'name': 'Schoerfling'}, {'OptionId': 2292, 'name': 'Weissenstein'}, {'OptionId': 2293, 'name': 'Home Office'}], 'name': 'Austria'}, '2249': {'cities': [{'OptionId': 9367, 'name': 'Oostende'}, {'OptionId': 2294, 'name': 'Antwerp'}, {'OptionId': 2295, 'name': 'Brussels'}, {'OptionId': 2296, 'name': 'Home Office'}], 'name': 'Belgium'}}
new_locations = {a:{c:d if isinstance(d, str) else sorted(d, key=lambda x:x['name']) for c, d in b.items()} for a, b in locations.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'2248': {'cities': [{'OptionId': 2289, 'name': 'Gramatneusiedl / Vienna'}, {'OptionId': 2293, 'name': 'Home Office'}, {'OptionId': 2290, 'name': 'Lenzing'}, {'OptionId': 2291, 'name': 'Schoerfling'}, {'OptionId': 2292, 'name': 'Weissenstein'}], 'name': 'Austria'}, '2249': {'cities': [{'OptionId': 2294, 'name': 'Antwerp'}, {'OptionId': 2295, 'name': 'Brussels'}, {'OptionId': 2296, 'name': 'Home Office'}, {'OptionId': 9367, 'name': 'Oostende'}], 'name': 'Belgium'}}
```

Edit: Python dictionaries are inherently unsorted, however, you can use a `collections.OrderedDict` to compensate:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_locations = OrderedDict()
final_data = sorted(locations.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]['name'])
for a, b in final_data:
   new_locations[a] = {'name':b['name'], 'cities':sorted(b['cities'], key=lambda x:x['name'])}
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('2248', {'cities': [{'OptionId': 2289, 'name': 'Gramatneusiedl / Vienna'}, {'OptionId': 2293, 'name': 'Home Office'}, {'OptionId': 2290, 'name': 'Lenzing'}, {'OptionId': 2291, 'name': 'Schoerfling'}, {'OptionId': 2292, 'name': 'Weissenstein'}], 'name': 'Austria'}), ('2249', {'cities': [{'OptionId': 2294, 'name': 'Antwerp'}, {'OptionId': 2295, 'name': 'Brussels'}, {'OptionId': 2296, 'name': 'Home Office'}, {'OptionId': 9367, 'name': 'Oostende'}], 'name': 'Belgium'})])
```

Comment: @AnarBayramov the country value (`"name"`) is a dictionary key and thus is unsorted.

Comment: I need to sort by country and cities inside. sort by locations['name'] then sort by locations['cities']['name']